# WPF How do I setup proper data binding (XPath) on a textbox with an XML element or attribute?

Tags: xml, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Good day,
I've been trying to crack this for several days now to no avail.
I have a xml file and I'm trying to bind it's elements and attributes in a dynamic way to various textbox controls. I've tried different ways of going at this and but they've all failed.
This last attempt is with

```
<UserControl x:Class="L5RCharacterManager.CharacterHeaderControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:L5RCharacterManager"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <XmlDataProvider x:Key="data" Source="myXmlFile"/>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Label Content="Clan" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Source="{}" XPath="root/element/attribute" />
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
```

Thanks for you time.
Edit: a quick sample of the xml document I'm trying to bind.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <element1 attr11="Scorpion" attr12="" attr13="" attr14="" />
  <elements2>
    <element21 name="twentyone" value="21">
      <subElement1a name="twentyoneA" />
      <subElement2b name="twentyoneB" />
    </element21>
    <element22 name="twentytwo" value="22">
      <subElement1a name="twentytwoA" />
      <subElement2b name="twentytwoB" />
    </element22>
   </elements2>
</root>
```

Comment: To help you, a minimal example of the content of the XML file you are using is required.

Comment: I've added a quick example, sorry for the horrible naming convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examples:

```
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xmlData" Source="myXmlFile.xml"/>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding XPath=root/element1/@attr11, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                 Source={StaticResource xmlData}}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding XPath=root/element1/@attr12, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                 Source={StaticResource xmlData}}"/>
```

```
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.DataContext>
            <XmlDataProvider Source="myXmlFile.xml"/>
        </StackPanel.DataContext>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding XPath=root/element1/@attr11, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding XPath=root/element1/@attr12, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

But the editing results will not be automatically saved.
To do this, when you close the Window, get the XmlDataProvider and explicitly save it XML.

An example that implements the saving of editing results.

```
    public static class Handlers
    {
        public static EventHandler SaveXmlOnClosed { get; } = (s, e) =>
        {
            Window window = (Window)s;

            XmlDataProvider provider = (XmlDataProvider)window.Resources["xmlData"];

            string file = provider.Source.OriginalString;

            provider.Document.Save(file);
        };
    }
```

```
<Window ----------------------
        ----------------------
        Closed="{x:Static local:Handlers.SaveXmlOnClosed}">
   <Window.Resources>
            <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xmlData" Source="myXmlFile.xml"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding XPath=root/element1/@attr11, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                 Source={StaticResource xmlData}}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding XPath=root/element1/@attr12, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                 Source={StaticResource xmlData}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: The good news is following what was here I got it to work. Mostly... There were a few bugs, it didn't like the relative path to the file and when I gave it an absolute path the provider.Document throws an exception. 

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

provider was null.

Comment: I also need to bind the xml database dynamically so it'll update the textboxes and vice versa OnPropertyChange or OnLostKeyboardFocus. But using DynanmicResource fails as it tells me it needs to bind to a dependencyProperty, but I don't know how to add that. I mean I tried inheriting from Textbox and adding the functionallity but WPF won't let me. Says I'm trying to inherit from multple class when I do so.

Comment: " bind the xml database dynamically so it'll update" - It is not clear to me what you mean by this.
Maybe you mean that the content of the file "myXmlFile.xml" can be changed not only through the provider "xmlData", but also in another way.
And you want this provider to change its state according to the current data in "myXmlFile.xml"?

Comment: Yes pretty much.

Comment: This is not possible for many reasons.
1 - XML ​​file is not a database. And it is impossible to change any separate part of it. To change at least one symbol, you need to rewrite the entire file. To overwrite it means to delete the old file and create a new one with the same name.
2 - there is no way in Net platform to receive notifications about file operations from the file system. Therefore, there is no easy way to know when the file will be overwritten and you need to update its view.

Comment: 3 - XmlDataProvider is just a convenient way to get XmlDocument from file. It is possible to get several XmlDocuments from one file and they "will not know" anything about each other. There is no means of notifying one XmlDocument about changes to another XmlDocument.
4 - even in the XmlDocument itself, there are no notifications about changes in the values ​​of its nodes. In WPF, this notification is organized by the Binding itself. If you change the value not through Binding (with Sharp code), then no one will "know" about this change.

Comment: If I understand right, I load the xml file into XmlDataprovider then everything happens between the provider and the controls. When I'm done I have to export the provider back to the file by overwriting it with the current data?

Comment: Yes.
This is exactly what the SaveXmlOnClosed method does in my example.